# Undo a shortcut association, Vim

Tags: key-bindings

A few days ago, accidentally, I create a shortcut/keys association and now I can't use the '<>' key within Vim (outside of Vim, the key works just fine). That's a Spanish keyboard from which I can use all the other keys with its respective character/s.

Now, when I press the key, it paste whatever text I have copied/selected.

I've been looking inside `:help index`, `:verbose map`, `/etc/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`  for the association and I can't find it.

Where/how should I look for this? Any ideas about how to solve it?

Note: I have **no** admin rights, I'm using linux Suse at work and my vim is vim72.

Comment: Welcome to Vi & Vim SE! Let me ask some follow up questions to see if your problem is really related to Vim. Do you have the problem with the '<>' key only inside Vim, or also in the shell in the terminal? If you start Vim with `vim -u NONE -N`, do you still have the same problem, or does that key work now?

Comment: Can you clarify which key is the problem? It's one key that typically produces `<` and then produces `>` when used with the Shift modifier? Do you only have trouble with `<` or also with `>`?

Comment: Have a look at `:help unmap` and `:verbose map`. It’s also possible the mapping was saved by a session if you use those.

Comment: @filbranden Using `vim -u NONE -N` I have the same problem, the key is just next to "z" and has `<` in "regular" mode, and `>` using Shift, and I have troubles with both.

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble, I took a look to `help unmap` but couldn't find out how/which to use the commands, I will investigate further, thanks for the idea.

Comment: I've tried all the above, and nothing. I've even tried `:mapclear | mapclear <buffer> | mapclear! | mapclear! <buffer>` and nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mike If you can't reproduce this with `vim -u NONE -N`, then it's most likely this is not really a problem with Vim itself... Is it possible this is a problem with some other component, like your terminal? Or maybe remote access (SSH client)? Are you using something like screen or tmux? Is your `$TERM` variable properly set?

Comment: @Mike Is it possible the Vim package was updated on your machine? Try `rpm -qif $(which vim)` on your shell to see the install date of the Vim package. Does that seem to match when the problem started happening?

Comment: Also know that you *could* install a newer Vim package inside your home directory without admin rights, particularly if you have a compiler (`gcc`) and build tools (`make`) available... Would that be a possibility you'd consider?

Comment: @filbranden I'm accessing through SmarTTY, but the issue is only present inside Vim, at the promt line (and any other "place") works just fine. I've ran the command and the installation seem quite older (2016) than the problem.

Comment: @filbranden The compiler option seems to be the best, since I have both gcc, and make, is just that I have no idea about how to do that, but thanks for the option, I'm going to investigate it.